# IValueConverter.Convert doesn't get called on a OneWay bind

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

I have a boolean property (that does called `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the setter) that is bound to a button.IsEnabled property in my XAML. Currently I'm using a `TwoWay` binding, but this is causing problems and I only need a `OneWay` binding. My problem is that the converter I'm using doesn't get called beyond the first time the program starts up. I've put breakpoints in the setter and it gets called loads, but the `Convert()` method doesn't get called at all. Why is this?

Some code:

```
public bool IsSaving
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSaving;
        }
        set
        {
            _isSaving = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsSaving);
        }
    }
```

and the XAML:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsSaving, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource booleanToNotEnabledConverter}}"
```

The converter really just returns `!(bool)value` so the button gets disabled when `IsSaving` is true.

Comment: It suppose to work, check again all the related code. Are you sure when you change it to TwoWay it works directly ?

Comment: When I use TwoWay it gets called all the time

Comment: Can you slim down the code and post that code?

Comment: Is this Silverlight or WPF? I want to test it in the same environment.

Comment: Sorry, this particular project is Silverlight. I'd remove the WPF tag if I could.

Comment: Just did that for you ;) I will test now

Comment: The scenario you told worked for me.
did you put brakepoint on getter too? was it get called?
Are you anywhere in you code settin your buttons IsEnabled=true/false.(this can be the case as it will brake the binding)

Answer (score 2):

Some changes at runtime might cause the binding to break (since you bind to the DataContext + a relative path), if you use Visual Studio make sure to check the Output-window for any binding errors.

**Edit:** Since it has not been noted: That is a stardard binding and there is nothing wrong with the posted code, the problem has to be caused by the context.

Comment: Surely if there were binding errors it wouldn't call the converter at all? And also, if there were binding errors, TwoWay wouldn't work?

Comment: No, the converter could be called while the binding still works, then after it breaks the binding would just be ignored altogether. This is most certainly an issue of all your context because there is nothing wrong with that piece of code.

Comment: +1 for teaching me that Binding errors are logged in the output window.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I used and this works:

Converter:

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System;
namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public class BooleanToNotEnabledConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:BooleanToNotEnabledConverter x:Key="booleanToNotEnabledConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel Margin="100">

        <Button Content="Flip"
                Click="Button_Click" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsSaving}"
                   Height="20" />
        <Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsSaving, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource booleanToNotEnabledConverter}}"
                Content="Some Button" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        private Data _data;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _data = new Data { IsSaving = true };
            this.DataContext = _data;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _data.IsSaving = !_data.IsSaving;
        }
    }

    public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region IsSaving Property
        private bool _isSaving;
        public bool IsSaving
        {
            get
            {
                return _isSaving;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_isSaving != value)
                {
                    _isSaving = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsSaving");
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var p = PropertyChanged;
            if (p != null)
            {
                p(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, can you strip down your code to the bare minimum so that it still contains the problem and then post it? I had some quirks when I forgot to make the data class public. It can be as simple as that...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you invoke the PropertyChanged event handler with the correct string?

```
PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSaving"));
```

Comment: The property is gleaned from reflection so there's no chance of misspelling the property name.

Comment: Are you sure Silverlight has the security permissions to use reflection? Can you check this by testing my suggestion?

Comment: You can use reflection on public members.

Comment: Did you try without reflection?